# Print doc files in asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, doc

I am working on an asp.net mvc project. How can I open doc.file to print it from page? The only thing I can do now is downloading, however, I'd like to open it as print friendly file in sort of window.print()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you just supply correct content type. Then user can view the file inside the browser and print it.

However, if the browser doesn't have appropriate plugin, then user can only download the file.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    return File("~/MyDocument.doc", "application/vnd.ms-word", "MyDocument.doc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.doc` files are designed to be opened with MS Word (and at one point there was a Word Viewer presumably designed for this sort of thing).  There are also other apps (e.g. OpenOffice / LibreOffice) which will allow you to read & write MS Word documents with varying degrees of success.

So one option -- as @Win points out -- is to require that users have some compatible application installed.  You frequently see this with PDF files, the site will typically contain a link to download Adobe (Acrobat) Reader.  The external app will be used to display the file; if the app can run as a plugin the content will be displayed "inside" the browser.

If the app is primarily intended for users internal to your business, and they all have Office installed, then that's a perfectly acceptable solution.

If you want the content to be available people who don't have Office (and/or don't run Windows) it gets much more difficult.  You'd need to either:

- write an MVC view that will parse/render `.doc` files (not for the faint of heart)
- convert the content to some other format (PDF or HTML) that's more easily "consumed".